# Removing unknown domain from 'Entire Network\Microsoft Windows Networks'

Tags: windows, netbios

I've just started work as a network technician at a large company, yesterday I brought my home laptop in and plugged in on the LAN to get to my mail. Today I can see my 'home' domain under 'Entire Network\Microsoft Windows Networks', it shows my surname! How can I remove it? I don't want anyone to see it there.

I'm guessing it some sort of domain browser service, we have both 2003, 2008 and 2008 R2 servers. NetBEUI may have been enabled on my laptop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, check your corporate policy. You're probably not allowed to plug your home computers into the corporate network. I'd go slightly nuts if I found any of my users doing that. You'll be lucky if your work doesn't do the same. You should know better.

Without a WINS server on the network: You can't remove it manually. The NetBIOS Master Browser has it cached now and will retain that as long as it's caching policy is set for (default is 6 days). You'd have to shutdown all possible NetBIOS Masters Browsers at the same time to clear the collective cache (when the current MB becomes unavailable an election occur and the winner will become the new MB using it's local cache as the MB cache).

With a WINS server: The WINS server has the entry now. If you have access to that server you can delete the entry there. Otherwise it should expire after 6 days (be default); and will be tombstoned (actually deleted) after another 6 days (again by default).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I use my laptop on the train so I always have it with me, I should have resisted. Is there any command I can run to clear it?

Comment: @SeanD: Other than to shutdown the entire network... No.  It's just going to take some time.